# how to build a metadata driven generic system

Tags: design-patterns

I am building a meta data driven asset management system.
The product has a concept of assets. There are predefined asset types and the customer can extend the system by providing custom asset types.

I plan to implement this using metadata layer.

The meta data for each asset type will be stored as xml.
It will look like this :

```
<assetType>
<name></name>
<displayName></displayName>
<primaryKeys></primaryKeys>
</assetType>
```

I would have a class AssetType serialized out of this xml.

Customers will provide their own xml to plugin the custom asset types into system.

I am trying to brainstorm on all possible solutions here.
Is there any other way to write this module other than xml ?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language).

You can use another format of structured text.

There is an infinite amount of ways you can represent the data.

Choose something that is both human and computer readable - XML seems to fit the bill quite well (as well as being well supported it crosses platforms well).

Writing your own DSL will be more work, but if you distribute your own parser/validator with it, you can ensure that clients write valid data only.